# Why was the "-ista" suffix used for traditionally male jobs? Is it correct to use "-isto" variant?

Tags: word-choice, history

How come the feminine sounding suffix *-ista* is used for referring jobs such as *autista*, *commercialista*, *economista*, *giurista*, and *apprendista*?

I think that when the words for these jobs were originally created, they were predominantly practiced by man. Is it considered a grammatical mistake to use *commercialisto*, *economisto*, or *giuristo* etc when referring to a male practicing that job?

Comment: Note that the converse is also true. For example we use [`presidente`](http://www.treccani.it/vocabolario/presidente/) etc. even if the president is a woman (currently there's a change in this direction and some people have started to use `presidentessa` if the president is a woman).

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Not everything that ends with -a is feminine and not everything that ends with -o is masculine, so don't get mislead by that. The suffix -ista is neuter, it's valid for both sexes and this means that, of course, *economisto and *giuristo are not valid words.

The suffix comes from Latin *-ista(m)*, which in turn comes from the Greek *-istḗs*. It is called *agentivo* in Italian, and it is used for all types of jobs, some examples are those you listed.

If you can understand some Italian, you could check [Suffissi](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/suffissi_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) and [Nomi denominali](http://www.treccani.it/enciclopedia/nomi-denominali_%28Enciclopedia_dell%27Italiano%29/) in the Treccani site.